# Excel VBA: Error 9 (Subscript out of Range) when pasting from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to excel vba and have created this code that has been working for months, but all of a sudden has stopped working. I get runtime error 9 on the last line of coding shown and have been unable to solve the error.

```
Sub BuildInsulationMTO_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbSourceFNameandPath As Variant 'Source data file name and path
    Dim wbTargetFNameandPath As Variant 'Target file name and path
    Dim a As Integer 'used to increment wbTarget file name
    Dim x As Integer 'used in H1 C1 description section

    Dim i As Integer 'Row of Source MTO
    Dim j As Integer 'Row of Source Raw MTO
    Dim k As Integer 'Row of Target File
    Dim LastRowSource As Long 'Rows in source sheet
    Dim LastRowTarget As Long 'Rows in target sheet, prior to row deletion
    Dim y As Long

    wbTargetFNameandPath = "L:\15.0 Engineering\LNG 1\15.0 Project Work Packs\15.10 IFS Job Cards\TempMTO\IFS Insulation MTOs\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_IFSInsulationMTO.xlsx"
    a = 2

    Do While Dir(wbTargetFNameandPath) <> "" 'If target file name exists, creates incremented file name and loops til this new name doesnt already exist
        wbTargetFNameandPath = "L:\15.0 Engineering\LNG 1\15.0 Project Work Packs\15.10 IFS Job Cards\TempMTO\IFS Insulation MTOs\" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "_IFSInsulationMTO_V" & a & ".xlsx"
        a = a + 1
    Loop

    Workbooks.Add 'create & save target excel file
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbTargetFNameandPath
    Close

    wbSourceFNameandPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Source Data Excel File") 'select source data file
    If wbSourceFNameandPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(wbSourceFNameandPath, False)
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(wbTargetFNameandPath)


'**************************************************************H1 C1***************************************************************************************************
    i = 5
    j = 3
    k = 2
    LastRowSource = wbSource.Sheets("MTO (C1 H1)").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 5 To LastRowSource
        'Job Card Number
        wbSource.Sheets("MTO (C1 H1)").Range("D" & i).Copy
        wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & k & ":A" & k + 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: check workbook that is referenced by wbTarget.  see if it has a worksheet named `Sheet1`

Comment: it creates a brand new target excel file. 1st sheet is automatically named "Sheet1"

Comment: Does it crash on the first iteration of that loop (i.e. when `i` is `5`) or does some of the code you haven't shown get executed before it crashes?

Comment: what is the value of `k` when the code breaks?

Comment: k=2 & i=5 when the code fails

Comment: The only way I can see for `wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & k & ":A" & k + 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` to give a "subscript out of range" error is if "Sheet1" doesn't exist in `wbTarget`.  Place a `MsgBox wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Name` immediately before the line causing the error - the MsgBox should display "Sheet1".  If it crashes instead, that gives us some more info.

Comment: Yeah that failed also. I don't understand how this fails though...

Comment: Change the MsgBox to be `MsgBox wbTarget.FullName`.  Make sure that is what you think it should be.  Make sure that file has a sheet called "Sheet1".

Comment: BTW - `Close` seems strange - that should close any files opened using `Open filename for Input As #1` style statements.  Is that meant to be `ActiveWorkbook.Close`?  But I'm not sure how that could be affecting things unless you have some `On Error` statements that we aren't seeing.

Comment: Ok, so that MsgBox suggestion helped. MsgBox wbTarget.FullName shows the location of my wbSource file for some reason (which explains why Thomas' suggestion was coming up with the merged cells error on my source file, it was trying to copy onto the 1st sheet of my wbSource!!)

Comment: I just tested - if you try to open a workbook that is already open then the statement `Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(wbTargetFNameandPath)` sets `wbTarget` to the workbook containing the code (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to your use of `Close`.

`Close` is a VBA statement that closes files opened with the VBA `Open` statement.  ([MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/close-statement))  It is not a statement that will close workbooks.

Because you were not closing the workbook with the name `wbTargetFNameandPath` after you did the `SaveAs`, it was still open when you got to the statement saying:

```
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(wbTargetFNameandPath)
```

That statement, when used to try to open a workbook that is already open, sets `wbTarget` to refer to `ThisWorkbook` (which, I assume, is your "source" workbook).

---

So, to fix the problem, change

```
Close
```

to

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

---

An alternative method would be to use `wbTarget` to refer to the workbook from the moment that you create it, and not bother to close and reopen it:

```
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add 'create & save target excel file
wbTarget.SaveAs Filename:=wbTargetFNameandPath

wbSourceFNameandPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Source Data Excel File") 'select source data file
If wbSourceFNameandPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(wbSourceFNameandPath, False)

'**************************************************************H1 C1***************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked perfectly. Your a champ!

Answer (score 0):

Different versions of Excel have different naming conventions for new Worksheets.  Perhaps the version of Excel has changed.

Changing this line to use the Sheet Index instead of the Sheet name should fix the error.

```
wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & k & ":A" & k + 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

---

```
 wbTarget.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & k & ":A" & k + 16).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

After you get your code working I recommend posting it to CodeReview.

Comment: I get a very different error if I do this. This code starts complaining about the merged cells on the 1st sheet of my source file needing to be the same size (a sheet that this code doesn't use). This code was working fine 2 months ago when we last ran it, I don't understand what could have changed...

Comment: The file might be corrupt.  Try using [Excel VBA Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) to rebuild the file for you.